# candidate.toLowerCase is not a function. (In 'candidate.toLowerCase()', 'candidate.toLowerCase' is undefined) Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using `AutoComplete API` of material UI. there is an object of **top100Films** which contains the title and year of movies. My autocomplete works fine if i search with `top100Film.title` as shown in code

```
<Autocomplete
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title} // <--
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
/>
```

But if i want to search the movies with `top100Films.year` then i get an error message

```
<Autocomplete
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.year}//<--
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
/>
```

*candidate.toLowerCase is not a function. (In 'candidate.toLowerCase()', 'candidate.toLowerCase' is undefined)*

How can i use any other data field except `.title`

the code is in [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xots5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getOptionLabel` should return string while `top100Films.year` returns a number. change the `getOptionLabel` as below and it'll work fine:

```
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.year.toString()}
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-slebb?file=/demo.js:301-396)

Answer (score 1):

need cast year in to string [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-94bw7)