# Uncaught TypeError: candidate.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I am facing these error messages: `Uncaught TypeError: candidate.toLowerCase is not a function. I am using AutoComplete API in the material UI, but when I search in the input field, it will bring me to blank page.

[image: img]

These are my existing code:

```html
getOptionLabel={option => {
return (
  <>
    {option.name}
    <span className="**">{option.dob}</span>
  </>
);
}}
```

What I've tried, but didn't work (I followed this StackOverflow [candidate.toLowerCase is not a function. (In 'candidate.toLowerCase()', 'candidate.toLowerCase' is undefined) Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66813809/candidate-tolowercase-is-not-a-function-in-candidate-tolowercase-candida) guideline):

```html
getOptionLabel={option => {
return (
  <>
    {option.name.toString()}
    <span className="**">{option.dob.toString()}</span>
  </>
);
}}
```

Hope some one can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

**Option data:**

[image: 311]

Comment: From the link that you shared: _"`getOptionLabel` should return string"_. You're returning JSX (an object), not a string.

Comment: It has something to do with candidate being nullish. Try to add a null check before you convert to lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link that you shared: *"`getOptionLabel` should return string"*. You're returning JSX (an object), not a string. You can also see this in the [autocomplete API documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/) by looking at the **signature**.

[image]

---

Rather than trying to render JSX in the `getOptionLabel` prop and trying to return JSX from that, you can use the `renderOption` prop instead to display your options, for example, in **Material UI v5** you would do:

```
<Autocomplete
  getOptionLabel={option => `${option.name} ${option.dob}`}
  renderOption={(props, option) => <>
      {option.name}
      <span className="**">{option.dob}</span>
    </>
  }
  ...
/>
```

In **Material UI v4** you would change the `renderOption` function to use `option` as the first argument:

```
<Autocomplete
  getOptionLabel={option => `${option.name} ${option.dob}`}
  renderOption={option => <>
      {option.name}
      <span className="**">{option.dob}</span>
    </>
  }
  ...
/>
```

Comment: Hi Nick Parsons, I have used your method but not work for me, and the result errors I attached in my above question

Comment: Can you share what your `options` data looks like please?

Comment: Also, what version of Material UI are you using? v4 or v5?

Comment: I have share the options data in my question

Comment: I think it is v5

Comment: @FattSky It should work if it's v5, I've provided a v4 version that might also be worth trying (see my edit above)

Comment: Let me try to see v4 version. Thank you

Comment: You are right. V4 version is suitable for my code

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not returning a string, but you are returning html:

```js
getOptionLabel={option => {
return (
  <>
    {option.name.toString()}
    <span className="**">{option.dob.toString()}</span>
  </>
);
}}
```

Needs to be for example:

```js
getOptionLabel={option => {
    return option.name.toString();
}}
```

Comment: But I want also return HTML